# Do I really need PRIMARY KEY when using UNIQUE NOT NULL columns?

Tags: sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

My knowledge in SQL is limited and I would appreciate someone who could help me to clarify the use of `PRIMARY KEY` in the following circumstances. I created a table to support ISO country information. I'm using MariaDB 10 but I believe that will not be relevant for the kind of questions I have(?)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS python.country
(
   iso_code    INTEGER(   3) NOT NULL     ,
   iso_2_alpha VARCHAR(   2) NOT NULL     ,
   iso_3_alpha VARCHAR(   3) NOT NULL     ,
   short_name  VARCHAR(  32) NOT NULL     ,
   long_name   VARCHAR(  64) NOT NULL     ,
   flag_link   VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT(NULL),

   CONSTRAINT  CK_iso_code       CHECK       (iso_code > 0 AND iso_code <= 999)                                ,
   CONSTRAINT  CK_iso_alpha      CHECK       (
                                              iso_2_alpha RLIKE BINARY '^[A-Z]+$' AND LENGTH(iso_2_alpha) = 2 
                                              AND 
                                              iso_3_alpha RLIKE BINARY '^[A-Z]+$' AND LENGTH(iso_3_alpha) = 3
                                             )                                                                 ,  
   CONSTRAINT  CK_names          CHECK       (
                                              short_name RLIKE '^\\p{L}+(\\.?[[:blank:]]\\p{L}+)*\\p{L}+$'
                                              AND 
                                              long_name  RLIKE '^\\p{L}+(\\.?[[:blank:]]\\p{L}+)*\\p{L}+$'
                                             )                                                                 ,
   CONSTRAINT  UN_short_name     UNIQUE      (short_name)                                                      ,
   CONSTRAINT  UN_long_name      UNIQUE      (long_name)                                                       ,
   CONSTRAINT  UN_iso_2_alpha    UNIQUE      (iso_2_alpha)                                                     ,
   CONSTRAINT  UN_iso_3_alpha    UNIQUE      (iso_3_alpha)                                                       
   -- ???
   -- CONSTRAINT  PK_country        PRIMARY KEY (iso_code,iso_2_alpha,iso_3_alpha)

); -- ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
```

Question 1: Since all main columns (`iso_code`,`iso_2_alpha`,`iso_3_alpha`) are `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` does make sense to create a composite `PRIMARY KEY`? I "believe" it's waste of space and time when inserting new elements?

Question 2: Can I use `iso_code` safely has being the `FOREIGN KEY` in other table?

Many thanks.

Comment: how are you going to join this table in your queries? what are `iso_code`, `iso_2_alpha` and `iso_3_alpha`? should not be `iso_code` unique?

Comment: are you sure to put so complex validation rules into CHECK? this will be executed on each insert/update. but will you really insert random data? also in case of it fails your code will receive from DB just validation error. And you anyway will need analyze additionally what exactly field is invalid.

Comment: Many "relational purists" believe that elevating one candidate key as being somehow more superior than others was a mistake in SQL. Many "SQL tribalists" will tell you that every table must have a primary key. Which way you choose to go depends to some extent on which camp you wish to be in :-)

Comment: @skyboyer - Scalar calculations like these take next to no time to evaluate, especially in comparison to writing the record itself.  I'd rather actually enforce integrity, allowing the database to "fail hard" rather than "fail silently" when some bug causes `1000` to be inserted rather than `0` or `999`.  To suggest that the overhead is "too high" is to suggest that *(the far more expensive)* foreign key constraints shouldn't be used either.

Comment: @MatBailie I see, suppose was being too assertive. Was sure regexp check should be quite expensive, but it is not true, right?

Comment: @skyboyer - Compared to `<= 4` it's expensive.  Compared to checking a key against an index in memory, it's trivial.  Compared to writing to disk it's non-existant.

Comment: @skyboyer "Expensive" means nothing. "More expensive than" means something--given a cost-benefit relationship.

Comment: Just create a `PRIMARY KEY` over `iso_code` and `non-clustered` indexes for the other two columns, just in case.

Comment: (In SQL:) PK means UNIQUE NOT NULL. A FK declaration says its column list's subrow values MATCH subrow values for its referenced column list, which must be declared as PK or UNIQUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since all main columns (iso_code,iso_2_alpha,iso_3_alpha) are NOT NULL and UNIQUE does make sense to create a composite PRIMARY KEY? I "believe" it's waste of space and time when inserting new elements?

Your proposed PK is a superkey over existing keys. It's not necessary in and of itself. You could choose to declare one of your unique key constraints as a PK instead but it's not necessary.

> Can I use iso_code safely has being the FOREIGN KEY in other table?

If you also mark `iso_code` as a unique key in this table, that should work fine.

Some people would recommend that every table always have an autogenerated column marked as PK. That's fine so long as you *also* enforce the logical keys. Unfortunately, many people will just create that auto-PK and no other keys, which means your data is nonsense.

You've chosen (currently) to just have the logical keys. I think that's fine in this case, especially as several (`iso_code`, `iso_2_alpha` and `iso_3_alpha`) are likely to be more compact that the recommended autogenerated column.

Comment: Thank you. You've got the all point of my question. Yes you're right it's ISO 3166, that's why I didn't use any kind of autogenerated PK. Allow me another question. Can I assume by your answer that the design of this `TABLE´ is perfectly acceptable?

Comment: @JacintoResende - *I* would be perfectly happy with this design, but others may disagree and we'd start getting into "primarily opinion based" territory and a close.

Comment: @philipxy - I don't think the OP is talking about composite keys, but rather multiple independent unique keys.

Comment: @JacintoResende If you want a composite FK then you have to declare the referenced coumn set a composite PK or UNIQUE, because that's the rule, although the limitation/enforcement is implied by (each of) the constituent UNIQUEs. If multiple FK columns should refer to the same entity/row then you do want a composite FK.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm just telling the asker the rules. They ask about declaring a composite PK & my comment says when they might need to declare either a composite PK or UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on performance and efficiency but one thing with composite keys is that when you use them as a primary key, you have to repeat them in your foreign key. I.e, PK iso_code, iso_2_alpha, iso_3_alpha will be additional FK columns in all the tables related. You also have to then query by these 3 columns in your SQL queries. Bit of a PITA IMO when you can simply use a generic, unique self generating column.

If you can use iso_code and you are sure you never ever ever will have the chance to require inserting a duplicate iso_code that has a different iso_2_alpha, iso_3_alpha then go ahead.  But, you should future proof and make table more robust and anticipate the unexpected, use a new dedicated id column unrelated to the business, IMHO.

Comment: I gather from the naming that this is a representation of [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). It's an international *standard* for representing countries. ISO won't be introducing duplicates.

Comment: @Ichirichi : Thanks. That was also one of the issues. I'm trying to keep "things" as simple as possible. On the other hand as Damien_The_Unbeliever stated I'm using ISO 3166. So I have guarantees that such codes remain unique.

Comment: The use of a surrogate key simply moves the issue to a different place. There still needs to be a map between the logical keys and the surrogate key, such that the logical keys are enforced to be unique. Any schema that would allow a single logical key to refer to multiple surrogate keys would be a failure. Thus, unique constraints on this table make sense. Then, having a surrogate key can be considered superfluous or useful depending on the tables that refer to it.